# Python refresh variable to new value tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, refresh

I've managed to make a change the value of the var to the new image but it does not show on the GUI(tkinter).
was wondering if there is a way to refresh the the canvas or the variable to make the new image appear?

I'm very new to python so please take it easy on me.

```
 def clothesImage(self):
    n = 0
    def nextimage(event):
        nonlocal n
        while os.path.splitext(imagechange(n))[0] == os.path.splitext(getimage)[0]:
            n += 1
        print(imagechange(n))


    # output_dir = 'resized'
    def imagechange(n):
        dir = os.getcwd()
        ordereddir = sorted(os.listdir(dir))
        getimage = ordereddir[n]
        extention = os.path.splitext(getimage)[1]
        while str(extention) != ".jpg":
            n += 1
            getimage = ordereddir[n]
            extention = os.path.splitext(getimage)[1]
        return getimage

    getimage = imagechange(n)

    width = 400
    height = 533
    canvas = Canvas(self, width=width, height=height)
    canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
    image = Image.open(getimage)
    canvas.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    image_id = canvas.create_image(width/2, height/2, anchor="center", image=canvas.photo)
    canvas.bind("<Return>", nextimage)
    return image_id, canvas
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you're searching for is `canvas.update()` : it will (it's quite obvious) apply all the modifications and also activate the binded functions that has been triggered.

Comment: Hey I tired that and it didn't seem to work is there a certain way to make it work in this situation?

Comment: Do you have an Error message? When I try to execute imagechange(n) it doesn't work because of hidden '.DS_Store' files that are not separable in two parts if you're on Windows that might be an issue, if you're notI don't know if there are some

Comment: Can we see the whole programm? @JaysonAriate Also I can't run the last part of the function: " 'Image' has no attribute 'open' "

Comment: Can you email me on ja2graal@gmail.com? I will wetransfer you the project.